# octave standalone , example reports undefined reference to `octave::feval error

Tags: c++, linux, octave

When try to the 2nd example https://octave.org/doc/v5.1.0/Standalone-Programs.html#Standalone-Programs I got the following error :

```
embedded.cc:(.text+0x132): undefined reference to `octave::feval(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, octave_value_list const&, int)'
```

The -d option of the mkoctfile provides the following two g++ commands, where the 1st one works fine.

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 -c  -fPIC -I/grid/common/pkgsData/octave-v5.1.0/Linux/RHEL7.0-2017-x86_64/include/octave-5.1.0/octave/.. -I/grid/common/pkgsData/octave-v5.1.0/Linux/RHEL7.0-2017-x86_64/include/octave-5.1.0/octave -I/grid/common/pkgsData/octave-v5.1.0/Linux/RHEL7.0-2017-x86_64/include  -pthread -fopenmp -fPIC    embedded.cc -o /tmp/oct-EYDDih.o
```

and

```
g++ -std=gnu++11  -I/grid/common/pkgsData/octave-v5.1.0/Linux/RHEL7.0-2017-x86_64/include/octave-5.1.0/octave/.. -I/grid/common/pkgsData/octave-v5.1.0/Linux/RHEL7.0-2017-x86_64/include/octave-5.1.0/octave -I/grid/common/pkgsData/octave-v5.1.0/Linux/RHEL7.0-2017-x86_64/include  -pthread -fopenmp -fPIC -rdynamic  -fPIC   -o embedded  /tmp/oct-EYDDih.o    -L/grid/common/pkgsData/octave-v5.1.0/Linux/RHEL7.0-2017-x86_64/lib -L/grid/common/pkgsData/octave-v5.1.0/Linux/RHEL7.0-2017-x86_64/lib/octave/5.1.0 -loctinterp -loctave
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: have you run the command as reported ? `mkoctfile --link-stand-alone standalone.cc -o standalone`

Comment: The second line implies that mkoctfile expects to find the libraries liboctinterp.so and liboctave.so in the path `/grid/common/pkgsData/octave-v5.1.0/Linux/RHEL7.0-2017-x86_64/lib/octave/5.1.0`. Your error presumably implies that it failed to do so. So I suppose the first debugging step here would be to ask, does an liboctinterp and liboctave library actually exist in that location? (and are they of the appropriate permissions?)

Comment: PS, I can confirm that the example on that page compiles, links, and runs successfully on my laptop. (though, to run you need to provide the location of the libraries at the same time, i.e. using LD_LIBRARY_PATH)

Answer (score 0):

I found in the the root cause for this issue, there was an EDA tool (Cadence Xcelium) module loaded which let g++ point to its private version, when I replace g++ with /bin/g++ it works in my environment.